# pagination with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi i'm trying to get the pagination right with code igniter but it seems that it doesn't want to work correctly. I get the second page, but there the pagination disappears, I still got the right table though and I have 2 errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 0
Filename: models/evaluation_model.php
Line Number: 37

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: models/evaluation_model.php
Line Number: 37
```

The controller function:

```
function showEvaluations($offset = 0)
        {
            if($this->login->is_logged_in())
            {
                $limit = 5;
                $result = $this->evaluation_model->getAllEvaluations($limit, $offset);

                if ($this->session->userdata('type') == 'admin')
                {
                    $data['evaluations'] = $result['evaluations'];
                    $data['total'] = $result['num_rows'];
                    $data['notallowed'] = false;
                    $config = array();
                    $config['base_url'] = base_url("evaluation/showEvaluations/");
                    $config['total_rows'] = $data['total'];
                    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
                    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
                    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
                    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
                    $this->load->view('allevaluations_view',  $data);
                }
                else
                {
                    $data['notallowed'] = true;
                    $this->load->view('allevaluations_view',  $data);
                }


                //$this->load->view('allevaluations_view',  $data);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('login_view');
            }
        }
```

and the Model:

```
function getAllEvaluations($limit, $offset)
        {
            $q = $this->db->select('tblPunten.PK_PuntID, tblPunten.Titel, tblPunten.Score, tblVakken.Vak, tblUsers.username, tblUsers.Voornaam, tblUsers.Achternaam')
                          ->from('tblPunten')
                          ->join('tblVakken', 'tblPunten.FK_VakID = tblVakken.PK_VakID')
                          ->join('tblUsers', 'tblPunten.FK_UserID = tblUsers.PK_UserID')
                          ->limit($limit, $offset);

            $query['evaluations'] = $q->get()->result();

            $q = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)
                          ->from('tblPunten')
                          ->limit($limit, $offset);
             $tmp = $q->get()->result();
             $query['num_rows'] = $tmp[0]->count;
             return $query;


        }
```

Line 37:  `$query['num_rows'] = $tmp[0]->count;`

Comment: Verify that `$tmp` is an array, where index `0` is set, and that the object at index `0` has a member variable called `count`.

Comment: I did the exact same thing I did here on another project and it worked perfect there, so I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: ***Verify*** that `$tmp` is an array, where index `0` is set, and that the object at index `0` has a member variable called `count`.

Comment: By "verify," I mean, add `var_dump($tmp);` to line 36 and analyze the output.

Comment: On page 1 it gives: `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#26 (1) { ["count"]=> string(1) "9" } }` but when I click on the pagination to go to page 2 and so work with the offset, the array is empty

Comment: The issue is elsewhere. You have to backtrack to see why your query isn't returning anything on page 2. Double-check `$limit` and `$offset` to make sure they're being used correctly, and not throwing off the query.

Comment: lol, found it, i just needed to remove the limit at the second query.

Answer (score 1):

Found it, the second query:

```
$q = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)
                          ->from('tblPunten')
                          ->limit($limit, $offset);
```

must be without the limit:

```
$q = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)
                      ->from('tblPunten')
```

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter, `->result()` an object.

if you want in that form of array then we can use `->result_array()` so that we can get the result set in the form of array.

```
$tmp = $q->get()->result_array();//made changes
$query['num_rows'] = $tmp[0]['count'];//will work
```